# Fill the matrix with 2x1 tiles and minimize left spaces

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, breadth-first-search

I have given a matrix of size **5xN** in which few cells are blocked ,I need to fill the matrix using  tiles of size **1x2** such that left empty cells are minimum possible. We can place **1x2** tiles horizontally or vertically.
If I place tiles vertically at **cell(i,j)** then I have to print **1 (i,j)** otherwise print **2 (i,j)**. see the example below:

```
......
..#..#
##.#..             # -> blocked cells
##.##.             . -> empty cells
.####.
```

Solution for above matrix is:

```
2 (0,0) 
2 (0,2)
2 (0,4)
2 (1,0)
2 (1,3)
1 (2,2)
2 (2,4)
1 (3,5)
```

Final matrix:

```
######
######         (only one cell left empty)
######             
######             
.#####
```

I tried to solve using BFS but it is giving me time limit exceed, What other approach I can use to solve this problem optimally.

1<= N <=100

Comment: Assume that, for each of the 2^5=32 possible patterns of occupied/free cells in row i, you know the maximum total number of cells that can be filled in by placing dominos so that (a) they produce this pattern in row i and (b) no domino extends below row i. Now, for any given pattern of occupied/free cells in row i+1, you can compute the maximum total number of occupied cells that obey corresponding constraints for row i+1 by trying all ways of extending each row-i pattern. Also for row-i patterns with 2 gaps together, you only need to try one of the `=` and `||` shapes.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in **O(N)** time and space using a mix of brute-force and dynamic programming.

To explain this, I'm going to represent a rule imposed on a column of 5 cells as a binary number **b** (for example **10011**) where a **"1"** means that I place the left part of a horizontal tile on that cell, and **"0"** means I don't.

Now, you can define a DP table of size **(N+1)*32**  as follows:

- **DP[i][b]** is the minimum possible number of empty cells in the first **i** columns if the column number **i** obeys the rule represented by **b**. If it is not possible to obey rule **b** on this column (because of the obstructions in your input matrix, or because we are at the last column of our matrix and thus cannot place a horizontal tile), then **DP[i][b] = infinity**.

As a base case you have **DP[0][0] = 0** and **DP[0][b] = infinity** as I can not place any tile using **0** columns.

Then to compute **DP[i][b]** for **i>0**, for each  rule **b'** on column **i-1** that is compatible with rule **b** on column **i** you compute the following :

- **DP[i-1][b']** + the number of empty cells on column **i** if you obey the rules **b** and **b'** then put as many vertical tiles as possible on column **i**.

And set **DP[i][b]** to be the minimum among all such computed numbers. (Of course if rule **b** on column **i** is incompatible with the obstructions in your input matrix, then just set **DP[i][b]** to be **infinity**).

Once you have computed all these values (in increasing order of **i**), your answer will be **DP[n][0]** (as you can not put any horizontal tiles on the last column).

Comment: The right idea, but if "compatible with" means "there is a 0 in row i-1 wherever there is a 1 in row i", this can undercount empty cells: e.g. you would set DP[i][10000] = min(..., DP[i-1][00111], ...) + 0, which will undercount if DP[i-1][00111] wins that minimum, because even though row i-1 can be fully filled by placing a horizontal domino, that can no longer be placed once we place the vertical domino required by row i's 10000.

Comment: Using 2 separate DP matrices fixes this: one that includes the effect of placing horizontal dominos (use this to get the final answer at row n) and one that doesn't (use this for computing the next row of the first DP matrix). Also, please mention the initial obstructions.

Comment: I don't think I agree with your comment (if I understood it correctly), as I defined placing a vertical tile on line **i** as placing the upper part of the tile on line **i** (so no possible interfering with the horizontal tiles on the previous line). I just saw your comment on the question and you seem to be doing it the other way around, so that might be the source of the confusion.

Comment: As to the initial obstructions, that's what I meant when saying "if rule b on line i is incompatible with your matrix", but it might not be clear enough, I'll try to rephrase that.

Comment: @Tassle Can you dry run for this test case - https://ideone.com/Wd6DPG, answer should be 1

Comment: I gave you the idea, I'm not going to code it for you!
(Also I edited the answer as I had been using rows instead of columns)

Comment: @Tassle: Right, I did things a different way, but my comment on your answer is about your approach. Another way of describing the issue: "DP[i][b] is the minimum possible number of empty cells in the first i columns if the column number i obeys the rule represented by b" -- this definition allows the placement of as many horizontal tiles on row i as possible to minimise the number of gaps on row i, but your calculation for row i+1 may require some of these positions on row i that are occupied by horizontal dominos to be free (to make room for the bottom half of dominos having a 1 in row i+1).

Comment: For the 2x5 input with bottom row (row 0) = `..###` and top row (row 1) = `.####`, your algorithm will incorrectly report that 0 gaps can be achieved: DP[0][00000] = 0 (since no vertical dominos can be placed with their top cell in the bottommost row, and this leaves space for a single horizontal domino to completely fill all gaps), and then you compute DP[1][10000] = 0 (since a single vertical domino can be placed with its topmost cell in the leftmost position of row 1, leaving no other gaps in this row, so you will compute DP[1][10000] = DP[0][00000] + 0 = 0). But the correct answer is 1.

Comment: Oh I see where our misunderstanding comes from now. I was numbering my rows from top to bottom (and now my columns from left to right after editing my answer, but I doubt that there may still be confusions in this case).